# How to authenticate username and password using keychain

Tags: ios, authentication, keychain

I am working on creating an app login details. I have gone through keychain and i was able to create keychain wrapper. But the problem is how can we authenticate username and password details entered in login page.I have programmed to set username and password using he following

```
[keychainItem setObject:@"password you are saving" forKey:kSecValueData];
[keychainItem setObject:@"username you are saving" forKey:kSecAttrAccount];
```

I was also able to retrieve username and password

```
NSString *password = [keychainItem objectForKey:kSecValueData];
NSString *username = [keychainItem objectForKey:kSecAttrAccount];
```

But the above retrieves the recently stored username and password pair. But i want to search the username and password fields and authenticate them. Can any one please help me on this

Comment: I'm also looking for this .___.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/6475/basic-security-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1

It does a great job explaining how to authenticate passwords and even offers a keychain wrapper class.  I believe this will answer your questions.